# Rich Text Box not loading Rich Text Format (ArgumentException) In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is the code:

```
mat.LoadFile(path + "\text.rtf")
```

mat is an rich text box. I double checked the path and the \text.rtf *does* exist. I'm *not* getting a "file not found" error, but rather a "file format not supported" even though it's .rtf
Exception Detail:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=File format is not valid.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(Stream data, Int32 flags)
       at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.LoadFile(Stream data, RichTextBoxStreamType fileType)
       at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.LoadFile(String path, RichTextBoxStreamType fileType)
       at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.LoadFile(String path)
       at Authorize.Form1.Form1_Load() in C:\Users\Hamoudy\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Authorize\Authorize\Form1.vb:line 18
       at Authorize.Form1._Lambda$__R0-1(Object a0, EventArgs a1)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you read the file in Word?

Comment: yes but it prompts me for conversion (encoding) every time. I usually pick Unicode-UTF8.

Comment: Seems your file either has a not supported encoding, or you're not loading it correctly. What happens if you try specifying the format too: `mat.LoadFile(path + "\text.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)`?

Comment: That .rtf file simply does not actually contain valid RTF.  Open it with Notepad to have another look at it.